# Why is the state overwritten by the attributes in the latest instance for all instances of a component when using IIFEs with Mithril.js?

Tags: javascript, iife, mithril.js

I'm trying out Mithril.js and have made three small components.

```
let Map = (function() {
    
  let Map = {};
  let parent;
  
  Map.oninit = function(vnode) {
    parent = vnode.attrs.parent;
  }
  
  Map.view = function(vnode) {
    return m("p", parent)
  }
  
  Map.onupdate = function(vnode) {
      console.log(parent);
  }
  
  return Map;
})();

let Popup = (function() {
    let Popup = {};
  
  Popup.view = function(vnode) {
    return m(Map, {parent: "Popup"});
  }
  
  return Popup; 
})();

let Dashboard = (function() {
    
  let Dashboard = {};
  Dashboard.view = function(vnode) {
    return m("div", [
        m(Map, {parent: "Dashboard"}),
      m(Popup),
      m("button",
      {
        onclick: function(e) {
            //Click event that doesn't do anything. Just added to trigger Mithril redraw
        }
      }, "Redraw")
    ]);
  }
  
  return Dashboard;
})();

m.mount(document.body, Dashboard);
```

The main outer component is Dashboard and is supposed to show the Map component and the Popup component. The Popup component shows another instance of Map. When showing the Map component I send in a string with the name of the parent component as an attribute, and set a local variable equal to the attribute. The Map component just returns a simple paragraph containing this variable to display the name of the parent component. The Dashboard displays two paragraphs containing the names of the parent components and a button so that Mithril will redraw when clicked.

On initialization it works as intended and shows a paragraph containing "Dashboard", a paragraph containing "Popup", and a button. The problem is that when I click on the button to update the DOM both paragraphs now show "Popup". So both instances use the latest value for some reason. I can fix this by rewriting the Map component to not be a IIFE, like so:

```
function Map() {
  let parent;
  
  return {
    oninit : function(vnode) {
      parent = vnode.attrs.parent;
    },

    view : function(vnode) {
      return m("p", parent);
    },

    onupdate: function(vnode) {
      console.log(parent);
    }
  }
}
```

[Link to JSFiddle showing the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/e54cLm81/37/)

Why does the version as an IIFE not work as I expected, and how could I make it work while still keeping it as an IIFE?

Comment: You don't have components with *instances*. There's only one single `Map` module in your code, which has a single `parent` variable. Why are you trying to use an IIFE when you want to create multiple separate objects?

Comment: @Bergi Seems I don't have a good understanding of how it works. I want to use the parent variable to make changes in how Map looks. For example if the parent is Dashboard I want Map to have a given size. So one Map might have a given size and all functionality while another Map might be smaller and have more limited functionality because the parent component is something else, like Popup. Should components be used like this, or am I misunderstanding how they are supposed to be used?

Answer (score 1):

Like @Bergi said, probably easier to drop the IIFE.  Here I converted what you had to use the closure style components seen here [closure-component-state](https://mithril.js.org/components.html#closure-component-state). You can use a POJO as a component but I wouldn't recommend it because the state is confusing.

When you were invoking the function immediately you would return a single Map object.  That object was used in Popup and so you would use the same object across all your code.  I'm sure someone with a giant brain *could* follow all the calls to determine the exact place either the value was only set once or the value was colliding but regardless you couldn't have parent set to the two different things on the same Map object.  It is surprising it works the first time but as you can see it is unreliable.

I removed the IIFE and renamed the components with a suffix of Component to make the code more clear.

```
let MapComponent = function() {
    
  let Map = {};
  let parent;
  
  Map.oninit = function(vnode) {
    parent = vnode.attrs.parent;
  }
  
  Map.view = function(vnode) {
    return m("p", parent)
  }
  
  Map.onupdate = function(vnode) {
      console.log(parent);
  }
  
  return Map;
};

let PopupComponent = function() {
    let Popup = {};
  
  Popup.view = function(vnode) {
    return m(MapComponent, {parent: "Popup"});
  }
  
  return Popup; 
};

let Dashboard = (function() {
    
  let Dashboard = {};
  Dashboard.view = function(vnode) {
    return m("div", [
        m(MapComponent, {parent: "Dashboard"}),
      m(PopupComponent),
      m("button", {
        onclick: function(e) {
            //Click event that doesn't do anything. Just added to trigger Mithril redraw
        }
      }, "Redraw")
    ]);
  }
  
  return Dashboard;
})();

m.mount(document.body, Dashboard);
```